# rssi returned by altbeacon library 127 messes up distance

Tags: android, ibeacon, rssi, altbeacon

I am working on an app that creates certain messages on entering different regions based on the range to a beacon (e.g. position < .5 | position < 2 | position < 10). I experienced a weird behavior while logging the distance and the rssi. Currently I am replacing the RSSI with the last received RSSI if it is 127. This is the only value that seems completely out of place.

**The Problem**

```
05-08 10:09:48.379  21495-22283 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 2533.712149492241 meters
05-08 10:09:49.500  21495-22284 I/RangingService? RSSI: -38 Distance: 0.07068384635393776 meters
05-08 10:09:50.662  21495-22301 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 0.07068384635393776 meters
05-08 10:09:51.795  21495-22302 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 2533.712149492241 meters
05-08 10:09:52.946  21495-22318 I/RangingService? RSSI: -34 Distance: 0.10971085339590038 meters
05-08 10:09:54.074  21495-22327 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 0.10971085339590038 meters
05-08 10:09:55.375  21495-22404 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 2533.712149492241 meters
05-08 10:09:56.499  21495-22488 I/RangingService? RSSI: -36 Distance: 0.08827424889527898 meters
05-08 10:09:57.637  21495-22492 I/RangingService? RSSI: -36 Distance: 0.008486821580451052 meters
05-08 10:09:58.771  21495-22493 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 0.08827424889527898 meters
05-08 10:09:59.902  21495-22509 I/RangingService? RSSI: 127 Distance: 2533.712149492241 meters
```

If you look at the distance, it will randomly spike with every calculation after or with the rssi of 127. I don't understand why the rssi would be 127 so randomly so often. Any ideas?

**The workaround**

```
int rssi2use = beacon.getRssi();
if (rssi2use == 127) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Using last Rssi " + lastRssi + " instead of 127");
    rssi2use = lastRssi;
} else {
    lastRssi = beacon.getRssi();
}
```

**MyBeacon.java**
Simplification of distance calulation to clean out the averages of rssis

```
public class MyBeacon extends Beacon {

    private static final String TAG = MyBeacon.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Beacon beacon;
    private final int rssi2use;

    public MyBeacon(final Beacon beacon, int rssi2use) {
        this.beacon = beacon;
        this.rssi2use = rssi2use;
    }

    @Override
    public double getDistance() {
        return mDistance = calculateDistance(beacon.getTxPower(), rssi2use);
    }

    public Beacon getSuperBeacon() {
        return beacon;
    }
}
```

**RangingService.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        beaconManager.setDebug(true);
        RangedBeacon.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(2200);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
```

I only listen for one speficic beacon.

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() == 1) {
                    Beacon beacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    handleBeaconInRange(beacon);
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(RANGE_REGION_ID, null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception on onbeaconServiceConnect", e);
        }

    }
```

There's more to handleBeaconInRange() that reacts to different distances, but this produces the log.

```
private void handleBeaconInRange(Beacon beacon) {
        int rssi2use = beacon.getRssi();
        if (rssi2use == 127) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Using last Rssi " + lastRssi + " instead of 127");
            rssi2use = lastRssi;
        } else {
            lastRssi = beacon.getRssi();
        }

        MyBeacon myBeacon = new MyBeacon(beacon, rssi2use);
        double distance = myBeacon.getDistance();
        Log.i(TAG, "RSSI: " + rssi2use + " Distance: " + distance + " meters");
}
```

**The Log:**

```
05-08 09:25:47.675  27646-29040/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -56 instead of 127
05-08 09:25:47.675  27646-29040/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -56 Distance: 0.7040448636262671 meters
05-08 09:25:48.839  27646-29041/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -56 Distance: 0.7040448636262671 meters
05-08 09:25:49.982  27646-29042/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -58 Distance: 0.97085 meters
05-08 09:25:51.121  27646-29043/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -58 instead of 127
05-08 09:25:51.121  27646-29043/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -58 Distance: 0.97085 meters
05-08 09:25:52.263  27646-29044/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -58 instead of 127
05-08 09:25:52.263  27646-29044/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -58 Distance: 0.97085 meters
05-08 09:25:53.408  27646-29045/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -55 Distance: 0.5879588872684474 meters
05-08 09:25:54.575  27646-29046/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -55 instead of 127
05-08 09:25:54.575  27646-29046/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -55 Distance: 0.5879588872684474 meters
05-08 09:25:55.701  27646-29047/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -54 Distance: 0.4893928979531776 meters
05-08 09:25:56.858  27646-29064/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -61 Distance: 1.1474711863884917 meters
05-08 09:25:57.991  27646-29074/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -61 instead of 127
05-08 09:25:57.992  27646-29074/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -61 Distance: 1.1474711863884917 meters
05-08 09:25:59.130  27646-29075/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -46 Distance: 0.09846874009910023 meters
05-08 09:26:00.247  27646-29081/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -46 instead of 127
05-08 09:26:00.247  27646-29081/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -46 Distance: 0.09846874009910023 meters
05-08 09:26:01.392  27646-29085/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -49 Distance: 0.18521700814366415 meters
05-08 09:26:02.534  27646-29086/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -49 instead of 127
05-08 09:26:02.534  27646-29086/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -49 Distance: 0.18521700814366415 meters
05-08 09:26:03.680  27646-29087/ I/RangingService? Using last Rssi -49 instead of 127
05-08 09:26:03.680  27646-29087/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -49 Distance: 0.18521700814366415 meters
05-08 09:26:04.823  27646-29088/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -33 Distance: 0.0035551625558338114 meters
05-08 09:26:05.967  27646-29089/ I/RangingService? RSSI: -37 Distance: 0.011161878866100936 meters
```

Comment: It sounds like you are getting bad readings from the hardware or the Bluetooth driver firmware on your mobile device.  Can you show your code for RangingService that spits out these log lines?    Are you calculating distance manually or are you using the built-in Android Beacon Library distance calculator?  The built-in library distance calculator already throws out the top 10% and bottom 10% of RSSI readings, so if you are using its distance calculations, that suggests that over 10% of your readings have this invalid RSSI value.

Comment: @davidgyoung I use the default library built-in calculator, but I set sampleExpirationMilliseconds to 2200. This however does not effect the outcome.

I will edit my question due to your request.

Comment: @davidgyoung Actually to do the workaround I simplified the getDistance() method in Beacon to see if the library had anything to do with those numbers.

Comment: Can you tell me the model of the phone you are using and Android OS version?  It appears that you are getting more than 10% of RSSI readings as 127.  I can put in a fix to the library to automatically filter out unreasonable RSSI readings like this, but I'd first like to understand what devices have the problem.

Comment: @davidgyoung I am using LG G3 S Android 4.4.2 / 5.0.2 both versions show this behaviour. I will test with this with different hardware from the same manufacturer. I am using Sensorberg's smallest version. Could this be a beacon-related problem that false signals are sent?

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with the LG G3 S.  The fact that you see the problem on two different devices suggests it is not a flawed unit, but an issue with the bluetooth chip or firmware on that device model.

Comment: I have built a beta release of the library which filters out RSSI readings of 127: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/releases/tag/2.3-beta1  Please try this and let me know if it resolves your problem.

Comment: @davidgyoung I am sorry for not being clear about the device. It's one device that's OS updated last weekend and still shows this behaviour. So it might just be my device not the model.

The beta version of the library does the job - thank you! It like the fix let it lag a little more? -I guess the more values of 127 the slower the calculation? ...while typing this I just got a log of 127 **once**.

Comment: @davidgyoung I just tested the scenario with a different device and you were right: a samsung device does not read 127 at all.

Comment: I also have a G3 S (jangm D722) and reports rssi readings of 127. I'm currently using LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2). Seems to be a hardware issue, or maybe the bluetooth chip driver was never fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to the library. It seems to be related to the used device, either firmware or adapter are spitting out wrong readings.

Thank you @davidgyoung for helping clearing this.